# Why does Eclipse not run the subprocess?

Tags: python, eclipse, subprocess

Really perplexed why this is not working. I have a python script which runs another python script as a subprocess using the subprocess module:

```
##### outerscript.py

import subprocess

subprocess.Popen("python testpython.py --newscript 'this is the argument'", shell=True)
```

The python script being run as a subprocess looks like this:

```
###### innerscript.py

import getopt

class Checkclass(object):

     def __init__(self):
         self.newscript = ''

     def check(self):
         print self.newscript 

     def complicatedcalculation(self):
         print 1+1


def argums(argv):
    checkclass = Checkclass()
    checkclass.check()
    checkclass.complicatedcalculation()

#Generates and interprets a list of options which can be passed as arguments to the class Checkclass
    try:
       opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], "h", ["newscript="])
    except getopt.GetoptError, err:
       print str(err)
       checkclass.usage()
       sys.exit(2)
    output = None
    verbose = False


    for o, a in opts:

        if o in ("-h", "--help"):
            #usage function not shown for simplicity-sake
            checkclass.usage()
            sys.exit()
        elif o == "--newscript":
            if a in ("-h", "--help", "--livescript"):
                print "need to define --newscript"
                checkclass.usage()
                sys.exit()
            else:
                checkclass.newscript = a

     checkclass.check()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    argums(sys.argv[1:])
```

When I run this script it generates an error stating

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "innerscript.py", line 45, in

Line 45 relates to the first line of the script to be executed i.e.

```
argums(sys.argv[1:])
```

The error doesn't seem to be that informative. I have been trying to come up with a solution for a while. I have tried running other more simpler python scripts through as subprocesses and they seem to work fine. I also can run this exact subprocess.Popen command on the terminal with no issue so it suggests it relates to the Eclipse IDE environment. When I look at sys.path on my terminal and IDE they are identical except that the Eclipse IDE also includes the paths relating to my Eclipse project folders.  I have seen others post issues regarding issues with Eclipse and subprocess 
[subprocess.Popen() has inconsistent behavior between Eclipse/PyCharm and terminal execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3460130/subprocess-popen-has-inconsistent-behavior-between-eclipse-pycharm-and-termina) but the issues and answer have not got me to a solution, but maybe it will help others with similar issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK i figured out what the problem was. The issue is not with the Eclipse IDE at all but it lies in my misunderstanding of how `subprocess.Popen` works. The `subprocess.Popen` class does not wait for subprocesses to finish. So because the function `argums` was calling further subprocesses the Popen class was not waiting for those subprocesses to finish hence script stalling at the top level process. If I replace:

```
 subprocess.Popen("python testpython.py --newscript 'this is the argument'", shell=True)
```

with either

```
 subprocess.Popen("python testpython.py --newscript 'this is the argument'", shell=True).wait()
```

or

```
 subprocess.call("python testpython.py --newscript 'this is the argument'", shell=True)
```

it now works. Hope this is of some help to someone else.

Comment: You don't need shell=true, pass a list of args  and if you want to wait use call or check_call

Comment: Thanks Padraic that works also. The docs actually discourage the use of shell=true https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments as it means the script is vunerable from malicious shell injection attack.